# How can I use a gravity form to send an e-card?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I have a Wordpress website that uses Woocommerce to sell printed greeting cards. We would like to enable our customers to be able to email people a digital version of a greeting card. I would like to use gravity forms to obtain the information like email recipient, to, from and personal message..etc. I don't know how to get Gravity forms to understand what product page the customer is being sent to the form from. I'd like to use the featured image of the product page as the image for the card that is being sent. I'd like to be able to include a link back to the original product page in the email.

I'm open to other ideas but, my employer would prefer that I use tools that we already have. I am able to do things like edit child theme functions.php. Thank you very much for any ideas on how I can create this e-card functionality.

Comment: The form is a separate page? You'll probably need to pass the ID of the product to the form page as a get or post parameter, and fetch the image etc. from there and then save the ID with the form e.g. as a hidden field. I can't remember how best to inject a value from query parameters into the form though sorry.

Comment: But for the Gravity Forms and WooCommerce bits you might to do better asking on their specific forums sorry.